# Convert float into time (hour.minute) in python

Tags: python, time

a = 08.94

here 08 is hours and .94 is minutes, i want to calculate 08.94 to 09.34

Please give me an idea,

Thanks in advance...

Comment: .94 is most likely a **fraction of a minute**, not 94 seconds.

Comment: Use your math skills.  But this seems like nonsense to me.

Comment: Hey @ jgritty, Use relevant words for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two cases:

```
a = "08.94"
asplit = a.split('.')
```

If the fraction is considered as minute:

```
print str(int(asplit[1])/60+int(asplit[0])) + '.' + str(int(asplit[1]) % 60)
```

If the fraction is considered as percentage of minutes:

```
print asplit[0] + '.' + str(int(float(asplit[1]) *  60))
```

Output:

```
9.34
08.5640
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

1. You misunderstand the data.

   Perhaps what you have is NOT something like `hh.mm`, but indeed fractions of a minute.

   So you have to do `hours = int(a); minutes = (a-hours) * 60`
2. The one who put that into a float misunderstood something.

   Then you can just do

   So you have to do `hours = int(a); minutes = (a-hours) * 100` which will essentialy put the first two decimals into `minutes`, maybe adding some decimals as well.

   If you then detect it is `>= 60`, you add one to `hours` and subtract 60 from `minutes`.

(In a former version of this answer I used the function [`floor()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.floor). It can be imported from `math` module and retuns the same value, but as a float. But it is better to use `int` in order not to need to import and to indeed get integer values for the hours, which might be cleaner in most circumstances.)

Comment: Why `floor()` and not `int()`? Hours are best expressed as integers, not floats (even if they have decimal portion).

Comment: @MartijnPieters `floor()` was the forst to come on my mind; `int()` should work as well.

Comment: Hi, can you explain "floor"?

Comment: @Jothimani `floor()` rounds downwards to the next integer value, but returns the value again as a float value, unlike `int()` which returns an integer type.